# How to cast User to Member during making Discord Bot with JDA? (Java)

Tags: java, discord-jda

I have a problem with creating a Member variable during making Discord Bot with JDA. I wanted to create a Member variable with a concrete User ID but I bump into a problem that not all users of my Discord server are visible for bot.

Here's the code that shows only 1 user instead of 3. (prints only bot name)

```
jda.getUsers().stream()
            .map(User::getName)
            .forEach(System.out::println);
```

Here's the code that causes an error.

```
Member member = event.getGuild().getMemberById("*************");
System.out.println(member.getNickname());
```

For example, this code works correctly (prints neccessary username)

```
User user = event.getJDA().retrieveUserById("*************").complete();
System.out.println(user.getName)
```

[Here's the error shown by IDE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2fhZH.png)

(I need Member variable to change userName using .modifyNickname that available only for Member variable)

Have you got any ideas to create a Member variable using userID? Or maybe I can somehow cast User to Member? Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at [GatewayIntent](https://ci.dv8tion.net/job/JDA/javadoc/net/dv8tion/jda/api/requests/GatewayIntent.html). Currently, the members aren't cashed.
Depending on your use case it may be sufficient to simply retrieve the member similar to what you did with the user.

```
event.getGuild().retrieveMemberById(id).queue()
```

Please note that using `.complete()` is not recommended. Stick to `.queue()` since it's asynchronous and won't block your thread.